# Find a relationship between the input voltage and the current through the diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, nmos, laser-diode

So my problem is to, just as the titles states, finding the relationship between the input voltage and the current through the diode for the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

We have also been given some parameters, namely that \$V_{DD} = 8 V\$ and \$k'/2 = 10 mA/V^2\$, furthermore we are neglecting channel length modulation. \$R = 200 \Omega\$. Lastly, we have that the laser diode is giving a constant output voltage of \$2.2\$ V when it's forward biased. Also, the op-amp is ideal.

My first idea is that we assume that the diode is not conducting any current. This means that the source voltage \$V_s\$ has to be smaller than that of \$U_{in}\$. Also, by KVL, we have that \$V_{DD} - U_{DS} - U_{D} - U_{R} = 0\$ where \$U_d\$ is the voltage drop over the diode, and \$U_R\$ is the voltage drop over the resistor. But since the diode is not conducting, both \$U_D\$ and \$U_R\$ are \$0\$. Hence \$U_{DS} = V_{DD}\$.

I have reflected about this, but I'm still lost and don't really know how to relate \$U_{in}\$ in all of this. I somehow would like to know the gate voltage \$V_{GS}\$, so that I can find the voltage at the source node, and therefore conclude the criterion for \$U_{in}\$ in which the current is \$0\$ through the diode.

I'd appreciate any tips that could help me continue to solve this problem.

Comment: by 'input voltage', do you mean 'Uin'? if so, then you don't need VGS, any more than you need VDD, if the amplifier gain is large. What is the resistor current at any given value of Uin? What is the diode current, as a function of the resistor current?

Comment: You need none of that. Do you understand how an op-amp works?

Comment: @Justme, do you *ever* sleep...you must be here 20 hours/day :-D Chasing that last 1600-odd will drain you... :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that if we assumed that the opamp is ideal. We know that inverting input voltage must be equal to the value at the non-inverting input. This means that \$U_R\$ must be equal to \$U_{in}\$.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, by input voltage I mean \$U_{in}\$. The diode current is equal to the resistor current since the op-amp is ideal, so no current will flow into terminals. So you mean that the current through the diode is just \$U_{in}/R\$? Just like that? If it's that easy, then for what \$U_{in}\$ does this hold? I mean the n-mosfet has to be active at least right, since we won't be able to get current through the diode then.

Comment: @Tanamas Yes, just like that, *up to the the voltage at which you run out of headroom*, otherwise known as 'saturation', 'hitting the rails', 'limit of linearity'. You might express the limit in the form of (I've not looked at the diagram again, and I know the details are wrong) as perhaps Uin < (VDD-VGS-Vdiode) sort of thing. There's another R drop in that righthand expression which is equal to Uin, which should go over to the lefthand side. Depending on the opamp (R2R or not), there might be a voltage less than VDD its output can't exceed. Below that, Idiode=Uin/R.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okay I see how it goes now. Thank you alot once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistor current = LED current = \$\frac{U_{IN}}{R}\$

The op-amp ensures this in order to maintain its two inputs at the same voltage (give or take the odd milli volt or so). The op-amp does this because it uses negative feedback from the top connection on resistor \$R\$.

The only constraints are that the power supply voltage is sufficient to get the required current flow through \$R\$ given that the gate needs to be maybe 1 volt to 5 volts higher than the source voltage. So, whatever voltage is needed across \$R\$ to get the required current flow, the power rail needs to be about 5 volts higher plus maybe 1.5 volts lost in the op-amp output.

Comment: Thank you Andy. As I commented above I just realized it. However, I wonder if there's any criterion for \$U_{in}\$ for which this has to hold? It surely can't hold for all \$U_{in}\$ I'm thinking. The GS voltage has to overcome the threshold voltage for the nmosfet in order for current to pass through it, otherwise it won't even be able to get to the diode? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Tanamas I added this as you commented. I also suggest you use a free simulator to verify this for yourself. It's a very common circuit used in many places BTW.

Comment: I'll try to use Multisim to confirm this, thank you for your tips.